# Security concern when sharing screen sessions

Tags: security, gnu-screen

What are the dangers involved regarding security in sharing a screen session with other users?

I plan to follow this guide: http://magazine.redhat.com/2007/09/27/a-guide-to-gnu-screen/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two main security risks there

- Making screen setuid root. This means that anyone who runs it can run it with root privlidges.
- The 'guest' user can run commands as the other user.

Screen is wonderful, but I'd avoid sharing it.